# Integrate Firebase with node.js and python

Tags: python, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Node.js as a backend for my Android application, with the help of Firebase Cloud Functions.
Is there any way I can also execute Python's methods from Node.js code?

thanks.